# Convert DateTime? to string in dd-MM-yyyy

Tags: c#, .net, linq, date, datetime

Im getting a value from db in a complete dateTime format, but need it to be converted it to string in the above format. I used dateTime.ParseExact but it seems to be not working with nullable type..please help

Comment: dateTime.Value.ParseExact?

Comment: If you need a string, then why are you using `ParseExact`? Shouldn't you be using `ToString(/*formatstring*/)`?

Comment: if `var dt is DateTime?`,   just use `dt.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")`

Comment: This is not a dupe of that question.  Wrong direction, @CamiloTerevinto.

Comment: @Amy yes, I know, I missclicked

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the Value property of the nullable DateTime object:

```
dt.HasValue ? dt.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") : string.Empty;
```

Replace 'string.Empty' with whatever you want to do if it is null.

Comment: MM not mm! If someone got something not expected. mm are minutes.

Answer (score 2):

[Null-conditional Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) in Visual Studio 2015 and above:

```
DateTime? d = null;

string s = d?.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");   // s = null
```

or string interpolation and `string.Format`:

```
string s1 = $"{d:dd-MM-yyyy}";                  // s1 = ""

string s2 = string.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", d); // s2 = ""
```

Comment: I feel like this should be the accepted answer.  A null-conditional operator returns null if the operand is null - which is how it should behave, instead of blowing up or returning an unexpected value

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just need to use the value property of the nullable field:

```
Datetime? readValue;
readValue.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

You should only need to use ParseExact if you are converting from a string.

Comment: DateTime? is nullable, hence above will return error in such condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Parse method to convert the string to DateTime

```
        Nullable<DateTime> d;
        d = DateTime.Parse("1996-07-12 00:00:00.000");
        if (d.HasValue)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(d.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
        }
```